# Unable to get invokeAction method result

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I'm trying to do:

Lightning component:

```
 <article class="slds-card" style="border: 1px solid #dddbda !important; border-radius: 0.25rem !important; " >
        <iframe 
                src="https://mydev.cs52.visual.force.com/apex/myVFpAGE?projectId=123321" 
                width="100%" 
                height="500px;" 
                frameBorder="0"/>
    </article>
```

IN VF Page:

```
var elementTree;
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(        
        '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getdata}',
        projectId,
        function(results, event){
            if (event.status) {               
                //elements = results;                  
                elementTree = results;
                console.log(elementTree); //**i'm able to get the result**
                
            }
        },
        {
            escape: false, timeout:3000, buffer: false
        }
);

console.log(elementTree); // **I'm unable to get the result here.**
```

Can you help me with the concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elementTree` is populated asynchronously. You cannot access it synchronously and obtain its value before it is populated.

This:

```js
        function(results, event){
            if (event.status) {               
                //elements = results;                  
                elementTree = results;
                console.log(elementTree); //**i'm able to get the result**
                
            }
        },
```

is a callback, which executes asynchronouly after the server call fired by `invokeAction()` completes. The synchronous code:

```javascript
var elementTree;
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(        
    // ...
);

console.log(elementTree); // **I'm unable to get the result here.**
```

has no access to this value because the server call hasn't completed and executed its callback yet.

Comment: Thank you very much David! Is there any way I can access callback result outside invokeAction scope in my VF page?

Comment: Sure, but not until the asynchronous call completes. Any action you need to take on populating that value needs to happen inside your callback.